# how to parse a local copy of pdf files and search keyword occurrence using javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, pdf, pdf.js

I am working on a window application where I have to look for all pdf files, parse them and search a keyword occurrence in them with the help of javascript. I tried using pdf.js but found no solution for local files. It shows me following error;
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Hello.pdf. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. (sample file name is Hello.pdf)

Comment: Why in Javascript? You wish it to run in a browser? Certainly *no one* you want to deploy this application to is going to let you read files from their hard drives. If you want to open that capability up to yourself, you can likely try and do it by running a web server on localhost.

Comment: If you are working on window application (I assume it's *windows application*), load local file using other means and pass it to the JavaScript code and convert it to the Uint8Array there, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This application will be used by only myself. I can have my local setup for it. I will run this application on remote server where I have bunch of files. I need to find out some word occurrence in those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PDFJS.getDocument` method accepts either a URL to a file, or an ArrayBuffer of the PDF file. So what you can do, is read the file into an ArrayBuffer (perhaps using `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer`), and then pass the buffer to `getDocument`.

[See here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L181).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it locally and it has to be JavaScript I would look for Node.js modules that can handle PDF's, like [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json).